# Why do I get error in printing this structure pointer?

Tags: c++, c, linux

My library (amqp C library) has a .h file called amqp.h which has this:

```
typedef struct amqp_connection_state_t_ *amqp_connection_state_t;

struct amqp_connection_state_t_ {
  amqp_pool_t frame_pool;
  amqp_pool_t decoding_pool;

  amqp_connection_state_enum state;

  int channel_max;
  int frame_max;
  int heartbeat;
  amqp_bytes_t inbound_buffer;

  size_t inbound_offset;
  size_t target_size;

  amqp_bytes_t outbound_buffer;

  int sockfd;
  amqp_bytes_t sock_inbound_buffer;
  size_t sock_inbound_offset;
  size_t sock_inbound_limit;

  amqp_link_t *first_queued_frame;
  amqp_link_t *last_queued_frame;

  amqp_rpc_reply_t most_recent_api_result;
};
```

I am trying to print the above values of the structure in my local test program:

```
amqp_connection_state_t state;
state = conn->getConnectionState( );
printf("Connection state values\n");
printf("Channel max: %d", state->channel_max);
printf("frame max: %d", state->frame_max);
printf("sockfd: %d", state->sockfd);
```

In turn I am getting the following compilation errors:

```
amqpoc.cpp: In function âvoid* con(void*)â:
amqpoc.cpp:85: error: invalid use of incomplete type âstruct amqp_connection_state_t_â
../common/amqp.h:294: error: forward declaration of âstruct amqp_connection_state_t_â
amqpoc.cpp:86: error: invalid use of incomplete type âstruct amqp_connection_state_t_â
../common/amqp.h:294: error: forward declaration of âstruct amqp_connection_state_t_â
amqpoc.cpp:87: error: invalid use of incomplete type âstruct amqp_connection_state_t_â
../common/amqp.h:294: error: forward declaration of âstruct amqp_connection_state_t_â
amqpoc.cpp:88: error: invalid use of incomplete type âstruct amqp_connection_state_t_â
../common/amqp.h:294: error: forward declaration of âstruct amqp_connection_state_t_â
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: Is this supposed to be C or C++ code.. Choose one.

Comment: We are using the rabbitmq C library, on top of that there is a C++ wrapper. The test code giving errors is compiled as C++ code

Comment: Which of the code you have shared are lines 85, 86, 87 and 88? It's just the 4 contiguous numbers make me think it some other lines with the errors. Which is line 294 in the amqp.h?

Comment: Try moving `tydef ...` line after structure definition.

Comment: @Rohan: Why are you suggesting me to change a library, which millions of people are already using and it's a 3rd party library.

Comment: @doctorlove: It's in library, Amqp.h (and already working by others)

Comment: Are you sure the library's public header defines the type? [This version](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/master/librabbitmq/amqp.h) certainly doesn't - the API treats it as an opaque type, with accessor functions like `amqp_get_channel_max()`.

Comment: I know it's in the library header - that's what the error says. Line 294 of the version of the header @MikeSeymour has posted says `AMQP_CALL amqp_version_number(void);`

Comment: @MikeSeymour   Amqp_private.h has the `struct amqp_connection_state_t_` and the typedef is in Amqp.h

Comment: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JESUS/Net-RabbitMQ-0.2.0/amqp_private.h

Comment: @kingsmasher1: And are you including the private header? (You probably shouldn't, but if you really want to subvert the interface and furtle with the stucture directly, then you'll have to).

Comment: ... otherwise the type will  be incomplete!

Comment: @doctorlove: Nope..the private header isn't included, we just include the Amqp.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct amqp_connection_state_t_` is for internal use. You are not supposed to access it directly. The amqp_connection_state_t type your code deals with is an [opaque handle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)

So, it appears your post isn't entirely truthful, the `struct amqp_connection_state_t_` declaration is NOT in the header file you include, it is in the `amqp_private.h` file, but you include `amqp.h`

If you want to get the `channel_max` , there is an access function for that:

```
  printf("Channel max: %d", amqp_get_channel_max(state));
```

The `->sockfd` member is exposed with the `amqp_get_sockfd` function. `->frame_max` seems however to not be exposed, so you can't fetch that.

You could probably get direct access to these members if you also include `amqp_private.h`, be aware that there will be compatibility issues when you do so if you use a different version of the amqp library at runtime than what the header files are created for.

Answer (score -1):

I think that problem is at command below:

```
state = conn->getConnectionState( );
```

Are you sure that the `getConnectionState()` function will return a amqp_connection_state_t type.
For sure,you should use `state = (amqp_connection_state_t)conn->getConnectionState( );`